# Combining multiple json schemas into a single json file with nested objects added to each endpoint

Tags: python, json

Hi I am currently trying to create a single json schema file from a few json schema files. I am looping through a list of jsons loaded, and output a single json with merged children objects.

Below is an example of an object that is present in both

```
object_in_first_list = 
  {
    "path": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "schema": {
      "name": "something",
      "children": {
        "child1": {
          "name": "child1"
        },
        "child2": {
          "name": "child2"
        }
      }
    }
  }

object_in_second_list = 
  {
    "path": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "schema": {
      "name": "something",
      "children": {
        "child2": {
          "name": "child2"
        },
        "child3": {
          "name": "child3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

These json objects are in a list that I am iterating over to create a unified JSON where the above objects will be merged and the output will be something like

```
  {
    "path": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "schema": {
      "name": "something",
      "children": {
        "child1": {
          "name": "child1"
        },
        "child2": {
          "name": "child2"
        },
        "child3": {
          "name": "child3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am currently iterating through the list using the two top level keys (path, name), putting them in a list(keywords), and then iterating over to add the endpoints to the new list(json).

```
    for jsons in json_list:
        for obj in jsons:
            keyword = {
                "path": obj["schema"]["path"],
                "name": obj["schema"]["name"],
            }

            # If keyword does not exist in the list add to non_duplicate
            if keyword not in keywords:
                keywords.append(keyword)
                updated_list.append(obj)

            else:
              # If Keyword matches
```